# Rotation program in C

Tags: c, math, rotation

I'm basically trying to make a math rotation program in C. But the output is always wrong. P(x,y) is rotated about Q(r,s); clockwise (direction=1) or anticlockwise (direction=0). The a,b,c are angles in triple ,I guess question meant c is in hundred's then b is in ten's and a is unit's.

Input:

```
   0
   7 3
   0 1 1
   0 0
```

Output: `-3 7`

Whereas I'm getting `-5 5`.

Thanks for your time if you help me.

Original question link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/DSPC305

i found another question by the same uploader which uses TRIPLE too. He further added a note :Triple is defined by a,b,c where a is base, b is height and c is hypotenuse of a triangle. Each triple corresponds to an angle given by cosA= a/c

```
    #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>

 int main() {
     int x,y,a,b,direction,c,r,s,xnew,ynew;

     scanf("%i", &direction);
     scanf("%i %i", &x, &y);
     scanf("%i %i %i" , &a, &b, &c);
     scanf("%i %i", &r, &s);

     float PI = 3.1415926535897932384626;
     float theta = ((c*100+b*10+a)*PI)/180;

     if (direction==1)
     {
          xnew= (x-r) * cos(theta) + (y-s) * sin(theta);
          ynew= -(x-r) * sin(theta) + (y-s) * cos(theta);
          printf("%i %i", xnew+r, ynew+s);
     }

     if (direction==0)
     {
          xnew =( (x-r) * ((cos(theta))) - (y-s) * sin(theta));
          ynew =( (x-r) * ((sin(theta))) + (y-s) * cos(theta));
          printf("%i %i", (xnew+r), (ynew+s));
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please replace all input with fixed values? Also, reduce your code to one direction. Then, there are a bunch of terms chained together, which of these terms isn't what you expect it to be?

Comment: Have you often participated in this? Is there something of a list of general definitions, which implicitly apply to all assignments? It seems that the exact meaning of "TRIPLE" is not defined in your question of the page you have linked.

Comment: I agree that the assignment is very unclear. According to the examples, the triple `0 1 1` must correspond to `90°` and `3 4 5` must correspond to `53.13°`. I have no clue what this could be.

Comment: i found another question by the same uploader which uses TRIPLE too. He further added a note :Triple is defined by a,b,c where a is base, b is height and c is hypotenuse of a triangle. Each triple corresponds to an angle given by cosA= a/c

Comment: Weird... But ok. The angle you need is then `atan2(b, a)`. If you make all your variables `float`, then your code appears to be correct. Alternatively, you can also directly use `b/c` as sine and `a/c` as cosine.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
float theta = ((c*100+b*10+a)*PI)/180;
```

has nothing to do with the definition of a triple.

Comment: so how do i solve then? can you guide me in this ques. You'd be a great help if you do.

Comment: @loneawolf: check the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    double xp,yp,xq,yq,a,b,c;
    double t,xn,yn;
    int z;
    scanf("%d",&z);
    scanf("%lf%lf",&xp,&yp);
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf",&a,&b,&c);
    scanf("%lf%lf",&xq,&yq);
    t=asin(b/c);
    if(z==0)
    {
    xn=xp*cos(t)-yp*sin(t)-xq*cos(t)+yq*sin(t)+xq;
    yn=xp*sin(t)+yp*cos(t)-xq*sin(t)-yq*cos(t)+yq;
    }
    else
    {
    xn=xp*cos(t)+yp*sin(t)-xq*cos(t)-yq*sin(t)+xq;
    yn=-xp*sin(t)+yp*cos(t)+xq*sin(t)-yq*cos(t)+yq;
    }
    printf("%0.lf %0.lf",xn,yn);
    return 0;
}
```

This code gave correct output for both of the test cases provided in the question.
Do tell if it worked :)

Comment: This will fail if the angle is larger than 90° or smaller than -90°.

Comment: Can you provide me with a test case so that I will modify my code accordingly or Any modification you want to suggest so that it will work.

Comment: Test case: Rotate the point `(1 0)` by the angle represented by the triple `(-1, 1, sqrt(2))` around the origin should produce `(-1 1) / sqrt(2)`. The suggested modifications are already in my comment under the question.

Comment: I changed sine and cosines with b/c and a/c respectively. It is giving me correct output for 2 test cases provided in question.But when I tried to submit that code on codechef it still tells wrong answer. Any further modification.